# In Spring does bean gets created first or Instance gets created first via Constructor

Tags: java, spring

```
@Autowired
    @Qualifier("stringMatchedBasedAnswerSuggestion")
    private SuggestionEvaluator stringMatchBasedEval;

    private List<SuggestionEvaluator> listEvaluators;


    public AnswerSuggestionServiceImpl() {
        if (listEvaluators == null) {
            listEvaluators = new ArrayList<SuggestionEvaluator>();
            // All the additional objects to be added.
            listEvaluators.add(stringMatchBasedEval);
            Collections.sort(listEvaluators, SuggestionEvaluator.compareByPriority());

        }
    }
```

In this case will the code inside constructor will be executed first or will the bean get created. Will stringMatchBasedEval be null or not ?

Comment: constuctor would be called first and then beans would be injected. I bet you are getting NPE.

Comment: Craig Otis and SMA   there are conflicts in your opinion

Comment: Java's call to the constructor is implicit in the object instantation, nothing can be done with the new instance until newInstance() has returned... therefore no injection will be possible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constructor will be invoked first and thus your `stringMatchBasedEval` will be null at the time. The problem is very general and there is a very common solution. In general your constructor should be empty and your initialization logic should be moved into separate method (Usually called `init()`) mark that method with `@PostConstruct` annotation and Spring will call it immediately after constructor and all the injections are finished. Thus your `stringMatchBasedEval` will be initialized already.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("stringMatchedBasedAnswerSuggestion")
private SuggestionEvaluator stringMatchBasedEval;

private List<SuggestionEvaluator> listEvaluators;


public AnswerSuggestionServiceImpl() {
}

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    if (listEvaluators == null) {
        listEvaluators = new ArrayList<SuggestionEvaluator>();
        // All the additional objects to be added.
        listEvaluators.add(stringMatchBasedEval);
        Collections.sort(listEvaluators, SuggestionEvaluator.compareByPriority());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In an injection approach, in order to inject a bean, you have to have the object on which you inject already created. After this, you have to set its beans. I think it is clear that first the object is created, and after this, the beans are injected.

So, firstly the constructor is executed, and after this, the beans are injected.

Comment: Worth mentioning that a method with @PostConstruct can be used to do any logic needed after everything injected...

Answer (score 1):

To inject something into object, spring should create object at first.

You can use constructor-based injection for your case:

```
@Autowired
public AnswerSuggestionServiceImpl(@Qualifier("stringMatchedBasedAnswerSuggestion") SuggestionEvaluator stringMatchBasedEval) {
    if (listEvaluators == null) {
        listEvaluators = new ArrayList<SuggestionEvaluator>();
        // All the additional objects to be added.
        listEvaluators.add(stringMatchBasedEval);
        Collections.sort(listEvaluators, SuggestionEvaluator.compareByPriority());

    }
}
```

Comment: For multiple dependencies this is not scalable... I'd recommend @PostConstruct method...